# npmbox fails to box react-scripts

Tags: reactjs, node.js, npm

im trying to migrate my react project to an offline computer so i need to box my dependencis.
one of the dependencis is called react-scripts, running `npmbox react-scripts` gives me error:

throw new Error('Unsupported URL Type: ' + arg)

Error: Unsupported URL Type: npm:string-width@^4.2.0
at parseUrl